# How to compare two dates FORMATS for saving to DB

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

I want to compare two **date formats** and return "false" when two **formats** are **not equal**.

For example, I get two dates, 24/10/2012 (DD/MM/YYYY) and 2016/11/05 (YYYY/MM/DD)... in this case some function should return false because date formats **are not equal**.

I want a function thats returns false when the second format to compare not equal the SQL format (YYYY-MM-DD).

Comment: Dates do not have an intrinsic format so your premise is faulty.  If you actually do have Date types (not strings with date data), just save them the  DB.  If they are strings, then parse them to a DateTime and send it to the DB (assuming the DB is using a Date column).

Comment: Are you asking for two functions, or does the question need some editing?

Comment: This is scary. It sounds like you're checking a date string for inclusion in an SQL command, and that in turn makes me wonder if you're using unsafe and dangerous practices for building your SQL, rather than parameterized queries, where format for the date _doesn't matter_.

Comment: Also: how do you know your second sample is YYYY/MM/DD and not YYYY/DD/MM?

Comment: why won't you convert your dates into a unique format? your question makes no sense for me. if you use SQL Server, you can use the `convert` function for that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are asking a question (or two) which does not need to be answered.

***Dates do not have a format***  Formats are how dates are displayed to humans.  A date is simply a very large number like `636094492018399433L`.  It does not have a format.

`I want a function thats returns false when the second format to compare not equal the SQL format (YYYY-MM-DD)`

You really need not worry about the db format using the NET DB providers (e.g. OleDB, SQLite, SQL Server, MySQL).  They all know how to properly store date data to a date column - its their job.  If your columns are string, **don't do that**.  If you want dates to act like dates, store them as dates.

Database docs bother to explain date formats for cases where you are entering data via a Shell interface from the keyboard, or perhaps importing data from a text/csv file.  When using the NET DB Providers, the data format is an *implementation detail*.

```
Using dbCon As New MySQLConnection(mySQLConnStr)
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(SQL, dbCon)
        dbCon.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fromDate
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = toDate

        cmd.ExecuteQuery
    End Using
End Using
```

- specify the `DbType` as `DateTime`
- pass it Date data.

To Store just the date, most DBs have a separate `DbType.Date`, but often you need to only pass the `.Date` portion:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = toDate.Date
```

The NET DB Providers all Know Things, like how to take a NET Date and save it to the database they were built for, and do so in a format it can parse/read back from.

Answer (score 1):

Try like

Dim matcher As Boolean = myString Like "??/??/????"

`28/11/1997; matcher = True` **BUT** `11/28/1997; matcher = True` (is also true)

It works for some patterns but not for everything maybe try splitting the date into more than one variable :)

Comment: or `#` for digits `Like "##/[01]#/####"`

Answer (score 1):

The question is confusing because it asks two separate questions. This is an answer to the second question which asks for a function that will test whether a date string is in the format "yyyy-MM-dd". It uses the `DateTime.ParseExact` method to test whether the string is in the required format.

```
Function IsCorrectDateFormat(testDate As String) As Boolean
    Dim myDate As DateTime
    Return DateTime.TryParseExact(testDate, "yyyy-MM-dd",
                                  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                  System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, myDate)
End Function
```