# Formatting Date value in vb.net still returning the wrong value

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, crystal-reports, format

The code below is the code I'm using to set the selection formula for my Crystal Report.

```
Dim dateTo As Date
 dateTo = dtpCRTo.Value.ToShortDateString
 dateTo = Format(dateTo, "dd/MM/yyyy")

If cmbCRSupplier.Value = "" Then
   selectionFormula = "{Sales_Headers.Stage} = '6' AND {Sales_Lines.PaymentDate} <= #" & dateTo & "#"
```

The issue I'm getting, is the data that I'm testing with has a `Sales_Headers.Stage` value of 6, which is fine, and a `Sales_Lines.PaymentDate` value of 30/11/2016 (In UK, `dd/MM/yyyy`) format, however, even though the `DateTimePicker` I'm using is showing 11th December 2016, the value of `dateTo` is returning as 12/11/2016, which is `MM/dd/yyyy` format, so the report shows no data, as that date is before the payment date.

Why is the date returning in this format, even though I'm formatting it?

**EDIT**

Also, before I put the formatting section in, and had `dtpCRTo.Value.ToShortDateString` in the selection formula, it still did the same thing.

For any dates where the day part is less than 13, it treats that part as a month, but works fine once the day part is 13 or more...

**EDIT 2:**

The query I have now is as follows:

```
 Dim dateTo As Date = dtpCRTo.Value.AddDays(1).Date
   dateTo = Format(dateTo, "dd/MM/yyyy")
   If cmbCRSupplier.Value = "" Then
    selectionFormula = "{Sales_Headers.Stage} = '6' AND {Sales_Lines.PaymentDate} < #" & dateTo & "#"
```

This works for all dates, except when choosing the last day of each month. If I'm selecting 31st January, the `dateTo` value will become 02/01/2017 (2nd February), which is treated in the formula as 2nd January. Is there a way around this?

Comment: unless `PaymentDate` is a text column, the format doesnt matter because dates do not have a format.

Comment: @Plutonix No, `PaymentDate` is `Date/Time` format, but even before adding in the formatting bit it was still not showing the data

Comment: a `DateTime` *type* will always have a date and a time portion, so using `<=` you dont want the time elements to exclude it.  Try this:  `dateTo = dtpCRTo.Value.AddDays(1).Date`  that should allow all dates with any time for that date to be included.

Comment: You should also turn on Option Strict. `Dim dateTo As Date = dtpCRTo.Value.ToShortDateString` is assigning a string to a date var

Comment: @Plutonix That first comment, setting `dateTo = dtpCRTo.Value.AddDays(1).Date` is now showing the correct data when the DTP value is 29/11/2016, but for any other date, before or after, it isn't showing it again

Comment: ...of course we have no idea what the data looks like or whats going on in the CR.  Remove CR from the mix and just work out the query portion.

Comment: @Plutonix After further checks, it's still doing the same thing... for dates before 30/11/16 it isn't showing it, when the dateTo value is 30/11/2016 is does show the correct data, but then it doesn't show it again for any of the dates in December before 12/12/16, because it's mixing up the month and day parts

Comment: The only way code will mix up day and month is when you are treating dates as strings somewhere.  A DateTime is just a value - a Big Number (today is 636209856000000000) - it represents the same moment in time whether the UK, US and even France.  Day and month are how that is expressed and displayed to humans.  No clue as to the query or data so there is little we can help with

Comment: @Plutonix Hmm.... When I save the values to the database, I'm declaring them as objects... Could that be it?

Comment: Could be - thats why the first thing I asked was how the date is saved.  If the column is date then pass date. See [How to compare two dates FORMATS for saving to DB](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39495617/1070452)

Comment: @Plutonix Yeah, your solution worked, it was the Object part that was throwing the issue. I've re-written that part to save it as a date and now it's working perfectly

Comment: I still dont know what the query looks like, so I have to guess.  Remember that DateTime types always have a date and a time portion.  If you pass just `.Date` the time portion will be zed.  But it means than the time elements *can* omit the first or last date depending on the query - note how that was solved in comment #2 for the ending date: you want it  to pick up all the times from the ending date from 00:00 to 23:59, so you just add a day

Comment: @Plutonix The query I have now is in Edit 2 of the post. It shows the correct data on every date, except for the last day of each month. This is because when adding the one day, the `dateTo` value will 02/01/2017 (1st February), when selecting 31st Jan, for example, but it's treating it as 2nd January

Comment: get rid of `Format(...)`  Dates do not have a format, if you want dates to act like dates, use dates.  Its been a while since I used CR but typically you would define a date parameter `dateTo` in it, and the formula would them be `...AND {Sales_Lines.PaymentDate} < {?dateTo}`  "formatting" the date to your culture is the problem because if anything, CR probably expects `InvariantCulture`.  Option Strict is still off.

Answer (score 0):

Format Properties:

```
1. DatePicker > Properties > CustomFormat > (Enter format you want here)
2. Properties > Format > Custom
```

Code Behind:

```
Dim dateFormat As String
dt.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
dt.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
dateFormat = dt.Text
```

Its either you want to format in Properties or in Code Behind.

Comment: Same problem I'm getting in the latest edit from @Plutonix's suggestion... When I pick the first day of a month on the date picker, it's still putting MM/dd into the formula, so the data that should be there, isn't