# date format is correct yyyy/dd/mm but its being displayed different dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: vb.net, gridview, date-format

This is so confusing me, I need to have my date formatted as yyyy/mm/dd which it is the case, when I register new user it will show error and only accepts that format however once I save their info, the date is shown as dd/mm/yyyy both on text and grid view.

Any idea whats the issue?

check my  custome validator ( it is fully working; the issue is odd)

```
   Dim testing As Date
    If Date.TryParseExact(txtentrydate.Text.ToString(), "yyyy/mm/dd",
                     System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                     Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, testing) Then
        args.IsValid = True
    Else
        args.IsValid = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think for month it should be `MM`, `"yyyy/MM/dd"`

Comment: Because the date is probably saved a `Date` so the cell will format it for display itself once it got the value and not use the input string. In the `DefaultCellStyle` property of the cell, adjust the `Format` property

Comment: Dates do not have a format - they are just a number  - so you cant "set" a format.  Formats are how we display them to users.  Your code is testing the format of a string not a date.

Comment: See also [How to compare two dates FORMATS for saving to DB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39495617/1070452)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable of type `Date` does not have a format. A date is just that - a point in time.

Only when a `Date` variable is *converted to string*, a format is assigned. So, if you say that

> ... the date is shown as dd/mm/yyyy both on text and grid view.

then your code which converts the date to its text representation is wrong. You did not show that code, hence we can only guess. My guess is that you *rely on implicit conversion*, which will use your current locale setting.

The solution is easy: **Explicity** convert your dates before showing them in the UI. You can do that by executing `ToString("yyyy\/MM\/dd")` when assigning them to your UI controls or by correctly setting some kind of "Format property" with controls that support data binding.

PS: [`mm` is for "minute".](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) You want to use `MM` in your format strings instead.

Comment: I've checked my database and it is storing in yyyy/MM/dd format! I still don't understand where I need to do the above Tostring conversion. here is my loadTextFields code: txtentrydate.Text = e.patient_entry_date

Comment: Dates do not have a format - it sounds like you are storing strings, not dates.  @Sam

Comment: I am sorry but It seems I am not getting this coz in Sql in Data Type column it says: date ?

Comment: DateTime.Now is **636370958525926352**.  That would make no sense to you or even heinzi or eric lippert (probably).  You are a human so whatever DB UI tool you are using is formatting it to `yyyy/MM/dd` so you can understand it.  Dates do not need to be formatted.  Strings are an entirely different datatype. See [DateTime Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) @Sam

Comment: Ah now it makes sense. Thanks lots. I will read up about it and try and sort out my issue! :)

Comment: Your database stored a date as a date, it has year, month and day information in it. Regardless of how you see it. When you retrieve the date from your database, it should be stored as a Date variable. Then you may format it however you want when displaying. You should not concern yourself about how your database shows it to you.

Comment: @Plutonix: Oh, yes, they *do* need to be escaped: Just `/` means [the locale-specific date separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator). If you want a literal `/`, you need to escape it. In C#, you'd need to escape it twice. ;-)

Comment: @Sam: Here, you use an implicit conversion: `txtentrydate.Text = e.patient_entry_date`. This would be an explicit conversion: `txtentrydate.Text = e.patient_entry_date.ToString("yyyy\/MM\/dd")`.

Comment: @Heinzi, I tried the above before but I was getting this error: Conversion from string "yyyy\/MM\/dd" to type 'Integer' is not valid. I also tried to surround the whole thing then with Convert.toInt32 but it seems I am still getting this error?

Comment: @Sam: What data type is `e.patien_entry_date`?

Comment: e is integer(patient id) so it's accessing that particular patient data. so its returning integer

Comment: @Sam: That does not make sense. If `e` is an integer, it does not have a `patient_entry_date` property.

Comment: Actually is of the Patient table type and between the brackets parsing the querystring patient id into integer. so you are right! my mate helped me, all I had to do was parse the database column date into dateTime and store it in a variable of type Datetime then on that variable I can do the toString("yyyy/MM/dd") conversion. Thank you all so so much! :)